# How can I access the property of a nested object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I need some help with accessing the property value of an object that is nested within another object.

I have this code:

```js
 var userStats = {
  'Jacob': {
    visits: 1
  },
  'Owen': {
    visits: 2
  },
  'James': {
    visits: 3,
  },
  'Ann': {
    visits: 4
  }
};
```

What I want to do is access the value of the visits.

I have tried:

```js
for(var firstName in customerData){
  console.log(firstName.visits);
}
```

But it is not working. It outputs 'undefined'.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `customerData[firstName].visits`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where `firstName` is a string which is the property name(or key) of the object so get object using the string.

```
for(var firstName in customerData){
  console.log(customerData[firstName].visits);
}
```

```js
var customerData = {
  'Jacob': {
    visits: 1
  },
  'Owen': {
    visits: 2
  },
  'James': {
    visits: 3,
  },
  'Ann': {
    visits: 4
  }
};


for (var firstName in customerData) {
  console.log(customerData[firstName].visits);
}
```

Comment: Or as earthiens call it: **A KEY**!

Answer (score -1):

I have made `customerData` an array of objects 'customers' and you can iterate them easily by swapping `in` for `of` in the for loop.

`for (var customer of customerData)`

**Example:**

```js
 var customerData = [
   {
     firstName: 'Jacob',
     visits: 3
   }, 
   {
     firstName: 'bocaj',
     visits: 2
   }
 ];

 for (var customer of customerData) {
   console.log(customer.firstName, customer.visits);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the contribution. I've found Pranav's solution straightforward and working as expected.